# Is it possible to access undocumented API members?

Tags: javascript

For example, the `AudioBuffer` object of the Web Audio API contains a number of array buffers that store the audio data. They aren't documented anywhere that I can find, yet you can access them by calling the `getChannelData` method, which returns a `Float32Array`. A reference to either that `Float32Array`, or its underlying array buffer must be stored somewhere in the `AudioBuffer` object, right? Could I extend the `AudioBuffer` object to access this `Float32Array` in some way other than through the provided `getChannelData` method? Obviously I would need to know its name, but assuming I did, could I access it? Or is it stored in some crazy, compiled format that I have no hope of getting at?

Comment: You can access all exposed functions and variables. But why don't you use a [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array) directly?

Comment: The specific problem that spawned this broader question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957824/manually-put-pcm-data-into-audiobuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property is not documented and doesn't show up when you inspect the object then it's most likely inaccessible. Consider the following, demonstrating how it's possible to prevent access to "private" data:

```
var Whatever = (function () {
    var hidden = 1;
    return {
        getHidden: function () {
            return hidden;
        }
    };
}());

console.log(Whatever.hidden); // undefined
console.log(Whatever.getHidden()); // 1
```